# How to download and load downloads image in Custom UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, image, uitableview, download

I get the text form the sever like this:

test_abc
http://www.xxx.a.jpg
test_aaa
http://www.xxx.b.jpg
test_ccc

I want to split the string to `["test_abc", "http://www.xxx.a.jpg", "test_aaa", "http://www.xxx.b.jpg", "test_ccc"]` and then display them in a `UITableViewCell`,before the images will be downloaded, I used a LoadingIndicator as placeholder, when the images will be downloaded, display the images and modify the height of the cell to display the whole images.

Can someone help me do this?

Comment: As your question is not clear , i suggest you to download images in document directory and then load the image from there like in shoemocracy app, please check that app

Comment: I suggest you to download Apple iOS guideline LazyTableImages(I shown reference url below) code and go through it. Url >> http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Listings/Classes_RootViewController_m.html

Comment: Thank u, I have downloaded it

Answer (score 0):

You may use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), and you don't have to worry about cache, etc..

Web Image
This library provides a category for UIImageVIew with support for remote images coming from the web.

It provides:

An UIImageView category adding web image and cache management to the Cocoa Touch framework
An asynchronous image downloader
An asynchronous memory + disk image caching with automatic cache expiration handling
A guarantee that the same URL won't be downloaded several times
A guarantee that bogus URLs won't be retried again and again
Performances!

Comment: 3ks, I will try use SDWebImage

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into [Three20](http://three20.info/)

An open source library written by the guy who wrote the official "Facebook" app for iOS. Moreover, the code of the facebook app is based on that library.